# Is using FB JavaScript SDK the most reliable option?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We use FB JavaScript SDK and we're loading it asynchronously, according to their docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

We use it to handle the login and for some basic calls to their API (mostly to publish stories and  share links):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Since we started using it, we have experienced different issues on some browsers and devices.

As an example, yesterday we experienced problems trying to post on the user's feed from an iOS device (FB.api('/me/feed', 'post'...)), this problem lasted several hours. Earlier, we experienced problems in other platforms such as IE.

It seems like FaceBook pushes changes to their SDK without testing properly on a wide range of devices.

My questions (not easy questions, I believe):

- Have you experienced similar problems. Do you think it is reliable?
- Is there any realistic alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the JavaScript SDK and it's been fine. Sure, there are issues from time to time, but that's part of being a Facebook developer.

The only alternative I can think of would be the PHP SDK. Both should be equally reliable.